# Massorny.js в Opera

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, html, javascript

Добрый день. Делаю показ блоков с помощью библиотеки massorny. Так вот везде(ДАЖЕ в ie) работает, а опере отказывается. Вот ссылка - http://bio.webadvert.tmweb.ru/catalogue/ . Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Что делаете вы не то, в Chrome не работает: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined jquery.masonry.min.js:10
Подключите не сжатую версию.

Comment: @Виталик Богачёв для класса bestsellers добавьте `clear:both`

Comment: RubaXa, подключил другую библиотеку, теперь выдаёт - Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined .
Yura Ivanov, поставил clear:both. Спасибо))